# What is the difference of stock_status and is_in_stock in stockItem object?

Tags: magento2, stock

code:

```
        $inventory = "http://example.com/index.php/rest/V1/stockStatuses/".$products_object->sku;
        $ch1 = curl_init($inventory);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token))); 
        $stock_item = json_decode(curl_exec($ch1));
```

debug:

```
    object(stdClass)#28 (5) { 
    ["product_id"]=> int(259) 
    ["stock_id"]=> int(1) 
    ["qty"]=> int(103) 
    ["stock_status"]=> int(0) 
    ["stock_item"]=> object(stdClass)#29 (26) { 
        ["item_id"]=> int(259) 
        ["product_id"]=> int(259) 
        ["stock_id"]=> int(1) ["qty"]=> int(103) 
        ["is_in_stock"]=> bool(false) 
        ["is_qty_decimal"]=> bool(false) 
        ["show_default_notification_message"]=> bool(false) 
        ["use_config_min_qty"]=> bool(true) 
        ["min_qty"]=> int(0) 
        ["use_config_min_sale_qty"]=> int(1) 
        ["min_sale_qty"]=> int(1) 
        ["use_config_max_sale_qty"]=> bool(true) 
        ["max_sale_qty"]=> int(10000) 
        ["use_config_backorders"]=> bool(true) 
        ["backorders"]=> int(0)  
        ["use_config_notify_stock_qty"]=> bool(true) 
        ["notify_stock_qty"]=> int(1) 
        ["use_config_qty_increments"]=> bool(true) 
        ["qty_increments"]=> int(0) 
        ["use_config_enable_qty_inc"]=> bool(true) 
        ["enable_qty_increments"]=> bool(false) 
        ["use_config_manage_stock"]=> bool(true) 
        ["manage_stock"]=> bool(true) 
        ["low_stock_date"]=> NULL 
        ["is_decimal_divided"]=> bool(false) 
        ["stock_status_changed_auto"]=> int(0) 
    } 

}
```

if i want to update a product from "no stock" to a positive interger, which one of them i need to update actually?

Answer (score -1):

1. `is_in_stock` : is a product stock status.

   **Database table** :  `cataloginventory_stock_item`.

   **Values** :  `(0, 1)`
2. `stock_status` : is product stock inventory.

   **Database table** : `cataloginventory_stock_status` item.

   **Values** : `(0, 1)`

> When you set the  `Stock Status` **product attribut** in admin,
>   Magento save that value in the both `is_in_stock` and `stock_status`, also for the product quantity, it set in the both tables, when the quantity is set to 0, Magento Update the `is_in_stock`, `stock_status` to **0**.
>
> `stock_status` display or not the product on front but there is also a
>   need to have `is_in_stock` otherwise you can't buy the product (Add
>   product to cart).